# curl request through c++ for indexing solr document

Tags: c++, curl, solr

I have used following code for indexing document in solr

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init(); 
CURLcode res;
if(curl) {
/* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
    data. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection1/update?replacefields=false  -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '[{\"id\":\"4000\", \"to\":\"Life is to.\", \"cc\":\"unknown \", \"subject\":\"Life\"}]'");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
     if(CURLE_OK == res){
        logger.LogError("res value CURLE_OK");
    }
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

and the return value of  curl_easy_perform(curl) i.e. res is CURLE_OK but the record is not indexing in collection1 of solr and while posting following command from terminal record is getting indexed

```
curl http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection1/update?replacefields=false  -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '[{"id":"4000", "to":"Life is to.", "cc":"unknown ", "subject":"Life"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not supplying cURL with your proper URL. Everything after the actual URL, `-H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '[{\"id\":\"4000\", \"to\":\"Life is to.\", \"cc\":\"unknown \", \"subject\":\"Life\"}]'`, is just arguments to the cURL command line tool, and is not part of the URL.

The URL option should be only `http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection1/update?replacefields=false`. The rest of the parameters has to be set as their own `curl_easy_setopt` calls.

To set the data to POST, use [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html).

> Pass a char * as parameter, pointing to the full data to send in a HTTP POST operation. You must make sure that the data is formatted the way you want the server to receive it.

To set the proper request content type, use [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html).

> Pass a pointer to a linked list of HTTP headers to pass to the server and/or proxy in your HTTP request. The same list can be used for both host and proxy requests!

After setting all the options call `curl_easy_perform`. You may also want to watch the log on the Solr server to see if Solr generates an exception. You can also set [CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.html) and [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) to get more information about any failure internally in cURL (CURLE_OK will be returned as long as cURL is able to make the request - but does not change if the server returns `400` or `404` or any actual error code on the server side (except if [CURLOPT_FAILONERROR](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FAILONERROR.html) is set).

Comment: Hi had tried above suggestion but in response on terminal i am getting error as :  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">5</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">missing content stream</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>

Comment: I think I am not providing parameter properly. how should i pass                 -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d                                               parameters

Comment: @Anuja That's kind of the content of my post. Use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to set the data to POST (the `-d` parameter) and `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to set a `Content-Type:`-header.

Comment: I had used CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to pass the json string([{\"id\":\"4000\", \"to\":\"Life is to.\", \"cc\":\"unknown \", \"subject\":\"Life\"}])   will you provide me the exact parameter sequence and values of curl to process data in solr